# Using virtualenv/virtualwrapper in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv, ubuntu-18.04

So I have this virtualenv called py3cv3 created using virtualwrapper. I am trying to set this enviromennt to be used with a Project  that I clone using GitHub. I am using Pycharm 2019.

But when I open the Project Settings, to set an Project Interpreter I can't select the default path where virtualenvs are installed(~/.virtualenv/).
I also tried do set  py3cv3 path as a Project Structure but Pycharm doesnt accept it. It just display the box in red color.

I already click at The option to show hidden folders and files,but Pycharm still not displaying the content from /root/ path.

Answer (score 0):

So,  i didnt find an answer. The only  way I found to get it right was removing everything related with envs and installing it again pointing to /home/username/. virtualenv.